# What is connected components?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[In this paper, page 5 Theorem 2.3](http://www.math.ntua.gr/~ppsarr/pseudfin.pdf) ,what is ***connected components*** of pseudospectra of matrix polynomial?

Comment: Well, do you know what "connected components" means in the general setting of topological spaces?

Answer (score 0):

In your context (where the space in question is $\Bbb C$), connected components are the same as path-connected components, which are somewhat easier to understand.

Let $X \subseteq \Bbb C$ be a subspace (i.e. subset) of $\Bbb C$. Consider the following equivalence relation on $X$: We say that $x \sim y$ if there is a continuous path $p: [0, 1] \to X$ such that $p(0)=x$ and $p(1)=y$. One says that $x$ and $y$ are connected by a path in $X$ if this holds. It's easy to check that this is really an equivalence relation on $X$. The (path) connected components of $X$ are the equivalence classes $X/\sim$.

As an example, consider the subspace $X = B_1(0) \cup B_1(3)$, where $B_\delta(z)$ is the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $z$. It's easy to see that pairs of points within one of the two balls can be connected by a path within that ball, but to get from a point in $B_1(0)$ to a point in $B_1(3)$ we have to leave $X$. It follows that $B_1(0)$ and $B_1(3)$ are the (path) connected components of $X$.